# How to impose that $u(x,y)$ must be bounded in terms of its Fourier transform?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider solving the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 u = 0$ on the upper half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with boundary conditions that $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $|u(x,y)|\leq M$.

If we Fourier transform the equation in the $x$ variable, we get

$$\mathfrak{F}_x[\partial^2_x u+\partial^2_yu]=-k^2 \mathfrak{F}_x[u]+\partial^2_y\mathfrak{F}_x[u]=0.$$

This is an ODE for each $k\in \mathbb{R}$ fixed that can be immediately solved to give

$$\mathfrak{F}_x[u](k,y)=A(k)e^{ky}+B(k)e^{-ky}.$$

Now the boundary condition $u(x,0)$ translates, to the Fourier transform, as $\mathfrak{F}_x[u](k,0)=\mathfrak{F}[f](k)$.

On the other hand we have the boundary condition $|u(x,y)|\leq M$. This "function must be bounded" boundary condition I'm in doubt on how to translate to the Fourier transform.

I mean, I have one very imprecise notion that: well, in the upper-half plane we may take $y\to \infty$ and then $e^{ky}\to \infty$ if $k>0$ so that we better get rid of that term so we may set $A(k)=0$ for $k>0$, the same for $e^{-ky}\to \infty$ when $k<0$ so that we may set $B(k)=0$ for $k < 0$.

This is horribly non-rigorous. So my question is how can we approach this rigorously? How can we impose the condition $|u(x,y)|\leq M$ when solving this problem via Fourier transform?

Comment: To write down a manifestly real expression for the final result compute the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-|k|y}$ and use the convolution theorem (you can determine $A$ from the initial condition). btw I assume $u < M$ only means $u$ is bounded and not that it will be bounded by some specific constant (that we cannot control as it's determined by $f$)

Comment: @Winther, I know that we can indeed make $A(k) =0$ for $k>0$ and $B(k)=0$ for $k < 0$. My problem is that I'm not finding out how to prove rigorously that doing so will give rise to a bounded $u$. As I said, I have one imprecise idea that this would be the way to have a bounded $u$ because otherwise one faces the issue of the exponential growth of $e^{\pm ky}$ as $y\to \infty$ when $k<0$ or $k>0$, but unfortunately by now I just have the intuition on that.

Comment: Will have to think some more about it, but I think we can argue soley based on existence of the Fourier transform. We can write down the general solution as $\hat{u}(k_x,y) = A(k_x)e^{-|k_x|y} + B(k_x)e^{+|k_x|y}$. If $u$ is bounded then it has a Fourier transform in both coordinates, however the last term here doesn't have a Fourier transform wrt $y$ unless $B = 0$ ($e^{|k|y}$ grows too fast so it is not a tempered distribution).

Comment: I think I got the idea. The condition that $u$ is bounded implies that $u$ has a Fourier transform in the two variables. The Fourier transform in the two variables is also the Fourier transform in $y$ of $\hat{u}(k_x,y)$. But this function does not have a Fourier transform when $B\neq 0$ because $B(k_x)e^{|k_x|y}$ is not in Schwartz space as a function of $y$. In that case, unless $B = 0$ the condition is violated. Is that the point?

Comment: Yes that is the main idea. The intuition about too rapid growth translates into this function not being in that class of functions. The only issue is that $u$ is only defined in the upper half plane so you have to figure out how to deal with this to make the argument sound (Laplace transform wrt $y$ maybe).